# Deploy React with Heroku

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku, graphql

Hi i'm trying to deploy my project with heroku but it's impossible i don't understand 
I already did like that on other project but this time it doesn't works in my server.js i have this code :

```
const express = require("express");
const graphqlHTTP = require("express-graphql");
const cors = require("cors");
const schema = require("./schema");
const path = require("path");

const app = express();

//allow Cross origin

app.use(cors());

app.use(
  "/graphql",
  graphqlHTTP({
    schema,
    graphiql: true
  })
);

app.use(express.static('public'));

app.get("*", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'public', 'index.html'));
});

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server started on port ${PORT}`));
```

In my app.js who is in my Client folder i modify uri for AplolloClient :

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Logo from "./logo.png";
import Matchs from './components/Matchs'
import MatchDetail from './components/MatchDetail'
import ApolloClient from "apollo-boost";
import { ApolloProvider } from "@apollo/react-hooks";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from "react-router-dom";

const client = new ApolloClient({
  uri: "/graphql"
});

function App() {
  return (
    <ApolloProvider client={client}>
      <Router>
        <div className="container">
          <img
            src={Logo}
            alt="Nba App"
            style={{ width: 300, display: "block", margin: "auto" }}
          />
          <Route exact path="/" component={Matchs} />
          <Route exact path="/match/:gameId" component={MatchDetail} />
        </div>
      </Router>
    </ApolloProvider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

in my package.json from my client folder i add a proxy :

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@apollo/react-hooks": "^3.1.3",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.3.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.1.2",
    "apexcharts": "^3.15.5",
    "apollo-boost": "^0.4.7",
    "classnames": "^2.2.6",
    "graphql": "^14.6.0",
    "lodash.flowright": "^3.5.0",
    "react": "^16.12.0",
    "react-apexcharts": "^1.3.6",
    "react-apollo": "^3.1.3",
    "react-dom": "^16.12.0",
    "react-icons": "^3.9.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
    "react-scripts": "3.3.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build && mv build ../public",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "proxy": "http://localhost:5000"
}
```

And i made a script to build and move in public/build
But when i deploy in heroku i have always

```
VM165:1 POST http://localhost:4000/graphql net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

But i don't know where he take this Url because i think i change all places where it could be problematic
Thanks a lot

Comment: There may be two things.

1. Server is not running.


2. It may have CORS Issue.

Comment: it's strange because i can access to https://appnbaalex.herokuapp.com/graphql when i try to change the new ApolloClient `const client = new ApolloClient({
  uri: "https://appnbaalex.herokuapp.com/graphql"
});`

Comment: There might be the case, if your application is down( I mean dynamos are not up), apollo client will not connect to the uri.